# Count the $n\times n$ binary matrices with odd/even determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

To be specific : 
How many $4\times4$ matrices with entries from $0$, $1$ have odd determinant?

P.S : Please do post comment/answer by fully reading it first and which satisfies what I asked for which I cleared at my best possible.

Approach : 
I didn't go for combinatorial approach as it was a multiple choice question .
So what i thought of is :
Consider Half of them are even and remaining are odd.
Total is $2^{4\times 4}$ so half would be $65536/2$ hence 2 of the options i have eliminated.
Now, One option was "20160" and other was "32767"  but reason i choose 1st option because there are some matrices with "0" determinant so it wont be "32767" , actually less than that so i go for "20160" .

But though I got correct answer , i wasn't satisfied by own intuition so tried it for $2\times 2$ matrix.
What I found is "10" zero matrices , "6" odd  and "0" even matrices. 
( I didn't considered "0" in the category of even just to separate it from odd/even)

With the $2\times 2$ matrix it didn't satisfy my above intuition of dividing into half.
So my question is  :

1. Whether I got the correct answer by luck?
2. Where my intuition gone wrong?
3. How to proceed with generalisation?

Comment: The ones with odd determinant are the ones that are nonsingular when considered as matrices over the field of two elements, and there is a standard way to count those.

Comment: Your comment didn't clear my doubt but i didn't go for standard way as this question need to be solve in 3 min and max 5 min. More than that wont be worth. And the standard method i found bit difficult. Any suggestions for solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189346/how-many-invertible-n-times-n-matrices-do-we-have-in-which-the-entries-are-tak?rq=1

Comment: It doesn't take very long to count the number of $4 \times 4$ invertible matrices over a field of size $p$.

Comment: how its related ? And that link didn't explain it well i guess but though thanx for sharing. Please answer the query if possible as its frequently asked in exams.

Comment: I want the number of odd/even determinant matrices over "n*n" if generalisazed.. Please do read the question with my queries :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in $\mathbb{F}_2$ the only possible odd determinant has value $1$ and the only even determinant has value $0$, implying the matrix is not invertible and thus the columns are not linearly independent.

Now this is just a counting problem that asks: How many matrices are there in $\text{M}_{4 \times
 4}\left(\mathbb{F}_2\right)$ with linearly independent columns?

For the first column, there are $2^4-1$ options, all columns except the $0$ column. For the second column, the only stipulation is that it cannot be the same exact column and it cannot be $0$, and it is linearly independent. So there are $2^4-2$ possibilities. For the third, it cannot be either of those columns or the sum or $0$, so there are $2^4-4$ possibilities. And for the remaining column, any possible candidates would have to be  not the sum of any combination of the three columns, for which there are $2^3$ sums (including $0$, the sum of none of them).

Thus, $(2^4-1)(2^4-2)(2^4-4)(2^4-2^3) = 20,160$.

I think your intuition would work reasonably well for fields with more elements, where the determinant would act more randomly.

Answer (score 2):

"Half of them are even and remaining are odd." is not correct.

According to [Consider the set of all $n\times n$ matrices, how many of them are invertible modulo $p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118080/consider-the-set-of-all-n-times-n-matrices-how-many-of-them-are-invertible-mo), the number of $n\times n$ invertible matrices modulo $p$ is 
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (p^n- p^i).$$
In your case $p=2$ and a matrices modulo $2$ is invertible if and only if its determinant is non-zero modulo $2$, i.e. it is odd. For $n=4$, the above formula yields
$$(2^4-1)(2^4-2)(2^4-4)(2^4-8)=20160.$$
On the other hand, the number of binary matrices with even determinant for $n=4$ is the cardinality of the complement:
$$2^{16}-20160=45376.$$

P.S. The number of binary matrices whose determinant is exactly zero is harder to find. For $n=4$ they are $42976$ which is less than the even ones $45376$. As a reference see http://oeis.org/A046747.

Comment: Among 2^16 permutations , if we remove #Odd matrices , How many of them are "Zero" Det. matrices from remaining 45376 ? Just add that so that I can select your answer

Comment: I stated that because I have not considered 0 matruces in even set.

Comment: Exactly zero is harder to find. For $n=4$ they are $42976$ which is less than the even ones $45376$. See http://oeis.org/A046747